# Python Datetime does not match format string

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-3.6, python-datetime

I am trying to parse a date with a specific format

This is my date string `2020-08-12 00:00:00 +05:30` 
Format string: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z`

Code that does the formatting:

```py
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format_str)
```

Output:
`ValueError: time data '2020-08-12 00:00:00 +05:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'`

Things I've tried:
Changing Zone from Caps to small `z` with format string as `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z`

Python Version: 3.6

Comment: in Python 3.6's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), the colon between hours and minutes of the UTC offset is not supported. and it's a lower-case `%z`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with lowercase z, and worked for me e.g.:

```
import datetime

date_string="2020-08-12 00:00:00 +05:30"
format_str="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"

date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format_str)


print('Date-time:', date_object)
```

prints

```
Date-time: 2020-08-12 00:00:00+05:30
```

**EDIT**

I'm using Python 3.7 so Sam's comment explains why it works for me.

Looking at the [3.6 datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), does removing the colon from the timezone work for you e.g.
instead of

```
date_string="2020-08-12 00:00:00 +05:30"
```

```
date_string="2020-08-12 00:00:00 +0530"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've told that I've already tried with a lowecase z and I get the same error

Comment: lowercase z [changed in 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail).  maybe a package like `python-dateutil` would be better, or you could work around with a regex to fix things up in older versions of Python